# HERE Geocoder API free-form text matching

Tags: here-api, geocoder

Is it true that using full country name in free-form text address will gain better "Relevance" scoring as compared to using CountryISO3 code?

In one of the example that I observed.
Case with country iso3 : Flat 1 Church Road, Liverpool, L37 8B,GBR

```
                    "Relevance": 0.88,
                    "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
                    "MatchQuality": {
                        "Country": 1.0,
                        "City": 1.0,
                        "Street": [
                            1.0
                        ],
                        "HouseNumber": 1.0,
                        "PostalCode": 0.98
                    },
```

Case with full country name : Flat 1 Church Road, Liverpool, L37 8B,united kingdom

```
                    "Relevance": 0.91,
                    "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
                    "MatchQuality": {
                        "Country": 1.0,
                        "City": 1.0,
                        "Street": [
                            1.0
                        ],
                        "HouseNumber": 1.0,
                        "PostalCode": 0.98
                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Relevance of the Geocoder API is explained below:

> Relevance is a precentage value ranging from 0 to 1 representing the percentage of the input that matches the returned address. "1" means that all input tokens were matched and there was no typo or any other difference.
>
> If the input query contains any additional information – name of the person, phone number or a hint to ring twice – the relevance will be low, but the address returned may be correct.
>
> Low relevance may indicate that the Geocoder API was not able to match some relevant part of the address in the input query.
>
> To separate the above cases one may look at match quality of the fields. These values show how well each of the address elements (e.g. street, city, country etc.) in the results matched to the input that was provided. If all the fields that are important for addressing in the country were matched with high match quality, one can assume that relevance is low because of the additional non-address information. And the result is still highly confident.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/scoring.html